# After intent "app rating" app switches to homescreen

Tags: android-intent, flags, rating

I want to open the entry of my android app in Google Play Store when the user pressed "rate my app". So I start a intent to support this feature, see code below. This works well, but when the user presses Back-Button while Play Store is shown, android switches to homescreen and my app isn't shown anymore. 
Additional info: My application is a game, so the main screen would be called by itself after game over or quitting a session. That means normally the user had to click 5 times Back-Button to close the application, after he played five rounds. So I set in the manifest

> android:launchMode="singleTop"

The intent is startet by following code:

> ```
>   case R.id.action_rate:  
>   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "..."));
>       //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>       startActivity(intent);          return false;
> ```

How am I able to solve this "bug"?

Thanks in advance 
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your activity is calling `finish()` in `public void onPause()`